# Connectivity loss in federated prometheus

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I'm considering setting up Prometheus monitoring stack using federation to handle issues with poor connectivity. My use case is the following:

- I have N separate small setups on-prem, each consisting of several machines and docker containers running on them
- Each of those setups is connected to the cloud, but connection is poor and can be lost sometimes
- I need to have a single prometheus instance in the cloud which would aggregate data from all those "small setup" on-prem

My idea was that local prom servers will scrape my jobs/machines etc and then using federation those metrics will land in the "central" prom instance.

Now, I'm not sure what will happen if I loose connectivity between cloud and on-prem. Am I going to download all samples from local prometheus servers, once connectivity is back? Or the central server will never learn about what happened during such network outage?